# how to use a timer to make text move from side to side?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, label, marquee

I have a label that I am trying to move side to side. I got it to work with a while (true) loop but decided to try and use a timer instead.

```
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 11;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (x <= 11)
        {
            x++;
            string ping = new string(' ', x) + "ping";
            label2.Text = ping;
        }
        else if (y >= 0)
        {
            y--;
            string pong = new string(' ', y) + "pong"; // this is where the exceptions given
            label2.Text = pong;
        }
```

that is as far as I have gotten it works sorta but after it does it once it throw the exception

'count' must be non-negative.

I am not sure how to fix this any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `y` reaches 0, it will still be decremented one more time.  Change to `y > 0` and you should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

`string()` constructor throws when you are passing negative value as the second parameter.

MSDN: [String Constructor (Char, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx)

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException - count is less than zero.

So just change

```
if (y >= 0)
```

to

```
if (y > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int x = 0;
private int y = 100;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (x <= 100)
    {
        x++;
        string ping = new string(' ', x) + "COURT DOCUMENT MANAGEMENT SYSTEM";
        label1.Text = ping;
    }
    else if (y > 0)
    {
        y--;
        string pong = new string(' ', y) + "MY ARCHIVE MY LIFELINE!!!!"; // this is where the exceptions given
        label2.Text = pong;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x <= 11)
{
    x++;
    string ping = new string(' ', x) + "ping";
    label2.Text = ping;
    if (x == 11)
    {
        y = 11;
    }
}
else if (y >= 0)
{
    y--;
    string pong = new string(' ', y) + "pong"; // this is where the exceptions given
    label2.Text = pong;
    if (y == 0)
    {
        x = 0;
    }
}
```